# rsync permission issue when run as systemd service in userspace

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, systemd

Ssh:d to a raspberry pi with Raspbian 11 I'm trying to create a userspace systemd service unit and timer for running an rsync command that would sync two folders under the home folder of the user I'm logged in as. (The .service is at `~/.config/systemd/user/` and enabled via `systemctl --user enable (service file name)`. If I run the rsync command (as the logged in user and without sudo) everything is OK. When I attempt to run the mentioned service (`systemctl --user start (service name` ) I get `rsync: [sender] opendir "/home/theuser/samba/projfolder/afolder" failed: Permission denied (13)` and the same for every subfolder in the projfolder folder (as well as a hidden file in the projfolder).

The permissions of one of these subfolders is : `drwxrws---  2 sambaservant servantgroup`
where 'sambaservant' is a local user tied to a samba user responsible for the samba share that I'm trying to copy. The user I am logged in with is a member of the "servantgroup" (hence why I can read and rsync said folder I think) as is the sambaservant.

The rsync command I'm trying to run is `rsync -av /home/theuser/samba/projfolder/ /home/theuser/local_backup_copies/`

The service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync Samba share proj folder to other folder

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=rsync -av /home/theuser/samba/projfolder/ /home/theuser/local_backup_copies/
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The rsync command succeeds as a service if the source directory and its contents are owned by the user I'm logged in as (as opposed to the directory I'm trying to copy from currently).

How can the rsync command succeed when I run it manually (as the logged in user) and fail when run via a systemd user space service?

Comment: Can you show `findmnt -u /home/theuser/samba`? What groups are you in (according to `id` with no parameters) when logged in normally, and what groups is your systemd --user manager in according to `systemd-run --user -qPG /bin/id`?

Comment: `findmnt -u /home/theuser/samba` outputs nothing, `systemd-run --user -qPG /bin/id` outputs `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`, `id` outputs `groups=1000(theuser),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),104(input),106(render),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi),1002(servantgroup)`. (This is logged in with theuser via ssh, by "normally" did you perhaps mean "locally"? It's a headless Pi but I can connect a display and mouse and keyboard to it

Comment: Do SSH sessions show up in `loginctl` on Raspbian? (Generally they should.) Does it still have the "dbus-user-session" package as a separate thing? (It contains the components that start dbus.service and allow systemd-run to work.) Was the Samba share mounted at the time you ran `findmnt`?

Comment: Yes, they do show up it seems. And "dbus-user-session" was an available not-installed package which I installed and after a reboot  `systemd-run --user -qPG /usr/bin/id` reports:  `uid=1000(theuser) gid=1000(theuser) groups=1000(theuser),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),104(input),106(render),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi),1002(servantgroup)` . Yes, the samba/projfolder was mounted, on the same system as I am ssh:ing from. That is to say the Pi is acting as a samba server.

Comment: Ah, so the service is running on the SMB server, not on the client?

Comment: The SMB server is the Raspbian system I'm sshing to. Other clients connect to its smb server and consume the contents of the home/theuser/samba folder. On this Raspbian system I wish to run the service which copies the /home/theuser/samba folder elsewhere on the same Raspbian system and in the same home folder.

Comment: I ran `sudo chgrp -R servantgroup samba/` and `sudo chmod 2770 samba/`, which I hadn't done since I filled the folder with content by mounting the share remotely, and then rsync could function when run as a userspace service. (I'm not sure exactly what it changed since the perms were like that already afaik). Was reading https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server . I need to read up on permissions and ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, but I don't have a solution, thought, I can answer this part from previous SystemD experiences:

```
How can the rsync command succeed when I run it manually (as the logged in user) and fail when run via a systemd user space service?
```

SystemD, in LP's infinite  decided to do cgroups/resource-containments/capability-limitations/etc.etc./etc.

The question that should be asked: `How to turn off those problems`